# Deploy Ember application after files are on DigitalOcean

Tags: ember.js, hosting, digital-ocean

I have a domain and would like to deploy my Ember application. I have a DigitalOcean account with a Droplet set up. I have the Droplet with DigitalOcean's servers linked to my domain. I followed Ember's deploy instructions by using `ember build` and using `scp` to copy the files over to root@myIPAddress. Now I have the ember build files in DigitalOcean's remote server but I don't know what I should do now to get my Ember application to actually show up on my website.

I've followed a Node.js tutorial for DigitalOcean (https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-a-node-js-application-for-production-on-ubuntu-14-04) but there isn't really much information that is helping in setting up an Ember application.

I've already tried searching everywhere for more instructions on how to deploy my Ember app to production but had no luck.

Comment: Did you ever get your Ember app running? I'm in the same boat. I have uploaded the `dist` directory to `/var/www/myembersite.com/public_html/` on Digital Ocean and I have edited the nginx `sites-available` to direct the proper port to `/ember` but all I see is a `502 Bad Gateway`. How do you actually serve the Ember app? `ember server` is no longer relevant.